# In the Bot Framework, Is there a common location where I can set the speak property to true in ChannelData?

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using the Bot Framework to build a speech enabled Bot which handles various events, and triggers a Dialog based on the event. The Bot is connected using WebChat as the interface. As this is mostly a proactive scenario, there is no prior input from the user. As a result, even though the dialog is triggered, there is no output speech, since the speech is activated only if the previous interaction was via Speech. To enable output speech, I right now have to explicitly set the ChannelData of every outgoing activity with 'speak' property as true using `activity.ChannelData = new {speak = true};`, which WebChat understands , and voices out the message associated with the Activity.

Is there a more efficient way to do this, by setting this property in a common location, so that all outgoing activities by default will be spoken out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run any code at all whenever the turn context sends an activity, you can use `TurnContext.OnSendActivities`:

```
turnContext.OnSendActivities(async (tc, activities, next) =>
{
    activities.ForEach(activity => activity.ChannelData = new { speak = true });

    return await next().ConfigureAwait(false);
});
```

This is often done with middleware, but you could possibly choose to do it at the start of your main bot logic.

Comment: Hi Kyle, I assume this would work in case of prompt using the PromptAsync() as well, since I assume it also calls the SendActvityAsync() method?

Comment: @ManishSridhar - Yes, the dialogs library sends activities through the turn context. Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Got it, I tried the same, and it works. Accepting this answer.